# Listar usuarios de Linux

Tags: linux, lista, grep

Se que se puede listar los usuarios, así como los grupos de Linux con un grep al

```
/etc/passwd-group
```

según el caso.

Ahora bien, cómo sería si quisiera listar solo los usuarios que tienen un ID mayor a 500 por ejemplo, y lo mismo para los grupos, pero sería la misma combinación para ambos, cambiando si es passwd o group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma muy simple es usar un script de `awk`. Por ejemplo:

```
gawk -F: '{if ($3 > 500) {print $1}}' /etc/passwd
```

Detalle:

- Con `-F:` establecemos los `:` como separador de campo
- Luego, simplemente con `{if ($3 > 500) {print $1}}` verificamos los valores de `uid` (columna 3) superiores a 500, en cuyo caso mostramos el nombre del usuario

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias y bien explicado!!!

Comment: Bien, el comando funciona si lo tiro directo en la consola.

Answer (score 1):

Claramente la solución con `awk` es mucho más práctica, pero por fines de entretenimiento, y porque pusiste la etiqueta de `grep`, propongo una forma muy rebuscada con expresiones regulares.

```
getent passwd | grep -P '^(\w+:){2}([5-9]\d{2,}|\d{4,})' | grep -Po '^\w+?(?=:)'
```

La primera expresión regular `^(\w+:){2}(([5-9]\d{2,})|(\d{4,}))`

Lo que busca es primero un patrón que es una palabra seguida de dos puntos, y eso lo busca dos veces, es decir, busca un, por ejemplo, "palabra:" dos veces. Luego, en un grupo busca dos patrones, uno que empiece desde 5 hasta 9, seguido de dos dígitos o una palabra con 4 dígitos o más.

La segunda expresión regular `^\w+?(?=:)`

Lo que busca es la primera palabra antes de los dos puntos, es decir, lo que esté entre el comienzo `^` y dos puntos `(?=:)`.

Las opciones que uso de `grep` son:

- `-P` que habilita la expresiones regulares de perl (son poderosísimas).
- `-o` imprime únicamente el patrón indicado.

Para hacerlo de forma más gráfica, propongo, valga la redundancia, esta gráfica para la primera parte `^(\w+:){2}([5-9]\d{2,}|\d{4,})`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, la verdad muy buena, pero a la vez y citándote es muy rebuscada. Obviamente mi nivel actual no nunca hubiera dado para tal solución.

Comment: @Vizz3rdriX Claro que es rebuscada, pero si te pediría que te quedaras con lo de las expresiones regulares como, literalmente, gráficas, autómatas o "máquinas" y no como meros buscadores de patrones.